# How can I get the process information in windows without using APIs?

Tags: c++, security, winapi, process, hook

I am writing a program to detect the hidden process. I can use C++ and Win32 APIs (like `zwQueryInformationProcess()`) to finish it. 
But what if those APIs are being hooked by hacker or someone else and make me cannot find the hidden processes as usual? Can I get those information without using APIs?

Comment: You want to obtain the information without executing any code? Easier to remove your malware.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just want to write a program to detect the process I hide ( I am a student of computer security. ). When I finish it, I consider the situation when those APIs I used are hooked and cannot work as usual. Then how can I improve my program.

Comment: At some point it's impossible to detect.

Comment: If the bad guy can hook the API, then they can patch your program so it doesn't find anything.

Comment: Actually, it's possible, but it's tricky and OS-Version specific. `ZwQueryInformationProcess` is just a little stub that performs a syscall. You can make the syscall directly, bypassing any user-mode API hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get this information without using an API.